# Execve is giving bad address

Tags: c

I'm having a little problem with the execve command. The program Test should create two children and each one should run an execve to load and run another program. But I'm getting a bad address on both the execve. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
    int child_1, child_2;

    child_1=fork();
    if(child_1==0){
        char* argv[]={"Test", "Test_1", "NULL"};
        if((execve("Test_1", argv, NULL))<0) perror("execve 1 fail");
        exit(0);
    }else if(child_1<0)perror("error fork");
    else wait(NULL);

    child_2=fork();
    if(child_2==0){
        char* argv1[]={"Test", "Test_2", "NULL"};
        if((execve("Test_2", argv1, NULL))<0) perror("execve 2 fail");
        exit(0);
    }else if(child_2<0)perror("error fork");
    else wait(NULL);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It won't cause an error *per se*, but it's suspicious that you `wait()` for the first child before forking the second.  If the two children are meant to run sequentially then that's just the way to do it, but if they're meant to run simultaneously then the parent should not wait until after it has forked both children.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It should work simultaneously, so I'll try what you suggested.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are not terminating the argument array correctly:

```
    char* argv[]={"Test", "Test_1", "NULL"};
```

`"NULL"` is a string literal, it's not same as `NULL`. The array needs to be terminated with a null pointer. Instead do:

```
    char* argv[]={"Test", "Test_1", (char*)0};
```

Similarly, fix the other argument array.

Answer (score 1):

or you have to change "NULL" to simply NULL.  In the case "NULL" you give NULL as a commandline parameter. The case NULL without " means end of argument list.